# How can I securely login remotely to my Linux box over the internet?

Tags: security, remote

What's the simplest, most secure way to connect to my computer at home from work or from the library, &c? I'm running Mint 14.  I'd like to connect from a Win or Linux setup.

ALSO is there an option to connect if you can't install software on the computer you're connecting from? Is there a browser solution?

Comment: Use openssh. Putty on windows.

Comment: Would you like to have access to your desktop graphical user interface or just shell access?

Comment: Shell access will do, but an example of both situations would be great.

Answer (score 3):

The safest way to log in to your Linux box would be through SSH, with password authentication *disabled*, key authentication enabled. [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) is an excellent Windows tool to access Linux machines over SSH.

For X applications you have to add an X-server (like [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) or [VcXsrv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/)) on your Windows machine and enable X-tunneling in PuTTY for it.

Answer (score 2):

For GUI you can also use `vncviewer` to connect to a remote [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNC) server, possibly tunneling the connection through `ssh`. `x11vnc` can be used on the remote side to export a currently running X11 session.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect in CLI mode, see jippie answer.

If you want to connect by GUI, I recommend you to take a look to [freenx](http://freenx.berlios.de/). It uses `ssh` in the background.