# How can I remotely access linux servers

Tags: linux, remote

I have a couple of servers that I need to remotely monitor. Is there anyway that I can do that? Should I use `vncviewer`, `ssh`, or what?

Comment: What do you need to monitor?

Comment: Duplicate?: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57977/how-can-i-securely-login-remotely-to-my-linux-box-over-the-internet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the time you will use `ssh`. `vncviewer` might be available, but often it isn't  (most servers will not have X11 or anything graphics-related).

Why use SSH? [From the CentOS documentation](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-ssh-intro.html):

> - After an initial connection, the client can verify that it is connecting to the same server it had connected to previously.
> - The client transmits its authentication information to the server using strong, 128-bit encryption.
> - All data sent and received during a session is transferred using 128-bit encryption, making intercepted transmissions extremely difficult to decrypt and read.
> - The client can forward X11 applications from the server. This technique, called X11 forwarding, provides a secure means to use graphical applications over a network.

Comment: What is so special about `ssh`?

Comment: It's encrypted, can be used for [tunneling](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html) and for file transfer (scp), among other features.

Comment: And of course you will turn off password authentication (in favour of key authentication) if you directly connect to Internet.